# Certificate for this server is invalid for self signed cert on swift 3

Tags: ios, ssl, swift3

I am using swift 3 and hitting a web service for the first time. My web service runs over HTTPS and I want to test with encryption in place.

Here's my code so far:

```
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default // Session Configuration
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config) // Load configuration into Session
    let url = URL(string: webService.getLoginUrl())!

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil {
            do {
                if let json =
                    try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]{
                    //Implement your logic
                    print(json)
                }
            } catch {
                print("error in JSONSerialization")
            }
        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

    })
    task.resume()
```

When I run this against my test server, which is self-signed, I get:

```
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “10.0.0.51” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

So what I'd like to do is accept all certificates when testing, but not in production.

I've found a couple of sites like:

http://www.byteblocks.com/Post/Use-self-signed-SSL-certificate-in-iOS-application
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/326

But these appear to predate swift 3.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much research, I learned about how delegates work with URLSession objects in swift 3. Too many pieces to post a link, but in the end, this was the most helpful: https://gist.github.com/stinger/420107a71a02995c312036eb7919e9f9

So, to fix the problem, I inherited my class from URLSessionDelegate and then added the following function:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

    //accept all certs when testing, perform default handling otherwise
    if webService.isTesting() {
        print("Accepting cert as always")
        completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
    }
    else {
        print("Using default handling")
        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
    }
}
```

The isTesting() call determines if I'm using the test server, and then we accept all certificates if we're in testing mode.

Comment: what is webService ?